# Adding directive to specific field

Tags: go, graphql, gqlgen

I created an Auth directive and passed it to just one query but seems like no query works if that single one fails. This is not the given expectation

#### What did you expect?

I want only the query to reflect this directive

#### Minimal graphql.schema and models to reproduce

```
directive @auth on FIELD_DEFINITION

type Data {
    code: Int!     
    status: String!  
    message: String!   
    packages: [String!]!
}

type PackageData {
    code: Int!     
    status: String!  
    message: String!   
    package: String!
}

type Query {
  completedPackages(limit: Int!, page: Int!): Data!
  getPackage(id: ID!): PackageData!
  activePackages(limit: Int!, page: Int!): Data! @auth
}

func Auth(ctx context.Context, obj interface{}, next graphql.Resolver) (interface{}, error) {
    tokenData, err := middleware.CtxValue(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if tokenData == nil {
        return nil, &gqlerror.Error{
            Message: "Access Denied",
        }
    }

    return next(ctx)
}

func GraphqlHandler(db *mongo.Database) gin.HandlerFunc {
    // NewExecutableSchema and Config are in the generated.go file
    // Resolver is in the resolver.go file
    c := generated.Config{Resolvers: &graph.Resolver{Collection: db.Collection("deliveries")}}
    c.Directives.Auth = directives.Auth
    h := handler.NewDefaultServer(
        generated.NewExecutableSchema(c))

    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        h.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)
    }
}
```

#### versions

1. `go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen 0.17.20`?
2. `go version 1.19`?
3. List item